# OCamlのExtLibのEnum

Tags: ocaml

OCamlのライブラリExtLibの中のEnumについて質問します。

以下を実行しました。

```
open Printf

let tee f e =
  let e' = Enum.clone e in
  f e';
  e

let term e =
  Enum.iter (fun _ -> ()) e

let f e =
  Enum.map
    (fun inp ->
       let out = inp * 2 in
       printf "in f\t%d\t%d\n" inp out;
       out)
    e

let () =
  let e = Enum.init 5 (fun i -> i) in

  e
  |> f
  |> tee
       (fun e ->
          Enum.iter (printf "in tee\t%d\n") e)
  |> term
```

結果は以下です。

```
in f    0   0
in tee  0
in f    1   2
in tee  2
in f    2   4
in tee  4
in f    3   6
in tee  6
in f    4   8
in tee  8
in f    0   0
in f    1   2
in f    2   4
in f    3   6
in f    4   8
```

上記のとおり、"in f"の行が全部で10行、出力されます。
期待していたのは、"in f"の行が5行、出力される動作です。

なぜ期待どおりの動作でないのかを教えてください。

Comment: なぜ5行出力されると期待されるのでしょうか

Comment: ソース中の下から5行目の`f`は、その前の行の`e`を引数にしています。
その`e`は0から4の5つの数を生成するので、関数`f`中の`printf`は5回だけ実行されると考えました。
何か根本的に勘違いしているでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clone`された列挙は元の列挙と独立して要素生成関数が消費時に呼び出されるようですね。ダブって出力されるのはそのためです。

メモリリークを避けるデザインだと思いますが、列挙は遅延リストとは違って`clone`されたからといって片方の要素生成の結果がメモ化されてもう片方に使われるというのではないと思います。生成要素を`clone`間で共有するには`clone`する前に`Enum.force`で明示的に要素を生成する必要があります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。理解できました。最初は遅延リストを使ったのですが、列挙でも同じと思っていたら動作が違うので、質問しました。